# How to get all of an objects properties, if one property found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with objects, which are props on a react component

```
this.props.items = [
    {make: Audi, model: A1, premiere: true},
    {make: BMW, model: X1, premiere: false},
    {make: Merc, model: C1, premiere: false}
]
```

I want to grab the details of the first object because it is

```
'premiere: true'
```

Which I can do like so:

```
this.props.items.map(x => x.premiere);
```

How can I grab all of the objects remaining keys and values and store them in them in state of the component?

```
{make: Audi, model: A1, premiere: true}
```

Comment: Through load dash lib : 
let  filteredTimes = _.map(items, function(o) {
    if (o.premiere == true) return o;
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array.prototype.filter instead of Array.prototype.map

Answer (score 2):

change `this.props.items.map(x => x.premiere);` to `this.props.items.filter(x => x.premiere);`